# unable to run npx react-native init in linux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu, command-line-interface

when I tried to create a react-native project with npx react-native init MyTestApp Error it pops up npx: installed 640 in 66.1s Unexpected token = and can not be created project

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need a different node version to be able to execute the command.